# Ghost Blog Error: var ghost = require('./core');

Tags: ghost-blog

I have a Ghost blog installed on shared hosting. I can access the blog by going to `blog.my-domain.com:2368`.

I want the blog to work when I go to `http://blog.my-site.com/` but that doesn't work. This is the page I see:

```
// # Ghost bootloader
// Orchestrates the loading of Ghost
// When run from command line.

var ghost = require('./core');

ghost();
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a solution. As it turns out port 80 was already being used. This is why it wouldn't work. I had to create a `.htaccess` file to solve the problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.example.com:2368%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

You replace `blog.example.com` with your URL for your Ghost Blog.

[Source of Information](http://blog.peterschmalfeldt.com/using-ghost-on-port-80-when-its-already-in-use/)